# Reading pipe delimited file* into array of structures C

Tags: c, structure

This program is suppose to read a pipe delimited file into array of structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_LINE 160
#define LEN_NAME 40
#define MAX_LINES 60
#define LEAGUE_NAME 5
#define PARK_NAME 35
#define TEAM_ADDRESS 40
#define TEAM_CITY 30
#define TEAM_STATE 5
#define ZIP_CODE 10
#define PHONE_NUMBER 30
#define WEB_ADDRESS 25
#define LEN_TEAM 60

typedef struct
{
    char leagueName[LEAGUE_NAME + 1];
    char teamName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char parkName[PARK_NAME + 1];
    char teamAddress[TEAM_ADDRESS + 1];
    char teamCity[TEAM_CITY + 1];
    char teamState[TEAM_STATE + 1];
    char zipCode[ZIP_CODE + 1];
    char phoneNumber[PHONE_NUMBER + 1];
    char webAddress[WEB_ADDRESS + 1];


} team_t;

void displayTeams( team_t teams[], int count);

int main( void )
{
    team_t teams[LEN_TEAM] = { 0 };
    FILE *filePtr;
    int index, count;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1] = {0};
    char *startPtr, *endPtr;

    filePtr = fopen( "MLBteams.txt", "r" );
    if ( filePtr == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        while ( index < LEN_TEAM && fgets( line, sizeof( line ), filePtr ) )
        {
            startPtr = line;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].leagueName, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].teamName, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].parkName, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].teamAddress, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].teamCity, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].teamState, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].zipCode, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].phoneNumber, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );

            startPtr = endPtr + 1;
            endPtr = strchr(startPtr, '|');
            strncpy( teams[index].webAddress, startPtr, endPtr - startPtr );



            index++;
        }

        fclose( filePtr );
        count = index;

        displayTeams(teams, count);
    }

    return 0;
}

void displayTeams( team_t teams[], int count)
{
    int index;

    for ( index = 0; index <= count - 1; index = index + 1)
    {
                printf("LEAGUE: %s\nTEAM: %s\nPARKNAME: %s\nADDRESS: %s\nCITY: %s\nSTATE: %s\nZIPCODE: %i\nPHONE#: %s\nWEBADDRESS: %s\n\n",
                                                     teams[index].leagueName, teams[index].teamName, teams[index].parkName,
                                                     teams[index].teamAddress, teams[index].teamCity, teams[index].teamState,
                                                     teams[index].zipCode, teams[index].phoneNumber, teams[index].webAddress);
    }
}
```

I am using this to try and read this file.

```
A|Baltimore Orioles|Oriole Park|333 West Camden Street|Baltimore|MD|21201|(410) 685-9800|orioles.com
A|Boston Red Sox|Fenway Park|4 Yawkey Way|Boston|MA|02215|(617) 267-9440|redsox.com
N|St. Louis Cardinals|Busch Stadium|700 Clark Street|St. Louis|MO|63102|(314) 345-9600|cardinals.com
N|Washington Nationals|Nationals Park|1500 South Capitol Street, SE|Washington|DC|20003-1507|(202) 675-6287|nationals.com
```

Here is a few lines(its 30 teams in total). Well when I run the program it crashes immediately and gives me no error messages.I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why the code isn't working.My guess is that I am using strncpy function incorrectly.

Comment: have you run in a debugger to see what `line` and other variables look like as it goes through?  Or perhaps just printed the values to `stdout`?

Answer (score 1):

In the given code it doesn't seem to be important to preserve the original strings. I'd suggest revising it to use strtok(), which modifies the original string by sticking NUL's in it as it goes. Specifically it puts a NUL character where the first delimiter is found, so then you can just use strcpy to copy the token. Then strtok with NULL will go back to the original string and find the next token for you. Read all about strtok() on the web.

```
while (index < LEN && fgets(line, sizeof(line), filePtr))
{
   char* token = strtok(line, "|");
   strcpy(teams[index].leagueName, token);
   token = strtok(NULL, "|");
   strcpy(teams[index].parkName, token);
   // and so forth
}
```

Now the problem I haven't solved, and you should, is that the supplied text could be too long for the field and neither your original nor my suggested code addresses this. Perhaps

```
token = strtok(line, "|");
if (strlen(token) > LEAGUE_NAME) token[LEAGUE_NAME]=0;
strcpy(teams[index].leagueName, token);
```

Also your strchr() results, and in my prototype code above, the strtok() results, are not checked. If the input line is wider than expected, your limited by count fgets() call could truncate the line and leave out a delimiter. The strchr or strtok result would be NULL and that would stop your program.

Comment: Thank you for the help, currently I am testing changes.

Comment: is it a case that I need to change the #defines lengths?

Comment: I mean it is working fine aside from the zip code. I was getting numbers for zip code without even writing code for zip code.It is pretty weird

Comment: I think your original code possibly could have been edited to work. If this were the case, I think Iharob-al-asimi 's suggestion of explicitly including NUL ('\0') characters would be one of the required edits. The choice I made was to suggest to you a rewrite which I think would make the code easier to maintain and point you to something which will be of value to yourself and others reading this in the future. Those considerations point to strtok().

Comment: If your code copies to the team[] elements properly the only bad effect you would have from #define is harmless truncation. It should therefore be safe to have #define's that are too small, and through testing, determine that the sizes are right. If the sizes are too small you'll see one or two fields get cut off, and you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You guess right! You need to manually `'\0'` terminate strings in this case, so using `memcpy()` might be better even in terms of clarity.

```
string[endPtr - startPtr] = '\0';
```

for each *`string`* in question.

Comment: Thank you for the help, currently I am testing changes.